# Incorrect amount of free space on 2009 Macbook

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, disk-utility

Recently, I've been noticing that my 2009 Macbook's storage has been plummeting. Despite cleaning my computer up, nothing seems to be working. I went to the apple store and we ran tests (which I already did) and tried re-repairing disk utility and so forth. (Which I'd already done) & (When I originally used disk utility it would work, now it doesn't work at all) Just says invalid block count and "repairs" it. But, I promise you I don't have 30gb left on my computer, especially when it said I have 84 gb. The day before.

I've had problems before with inaccurate free disk space (even when accounting for Time Machine's Local Snapshots). Usually though I can fix the problem by verifying the disk in disk utility, which then shows Invalid volume free block count and orphaned blocks errors, which I could then repair in recovery mode, but now disk utility repeatedly insists the volume is OK. Which I don't understand at all. All the space seems to be going to "other" even with Daisy Disk I don't know where to start.

I'm trying to install a new version of Maverick to see if this does anything, but the only option the guy from the apple store told me was to wipe my whole computer, and then drag everything back (not using time machine because that may still have the bug on it)

Ultimately, I'm not sure what to do. Should I clear it and then add everything back. I have a giant pain-in-the-rear iTunes library, my office and photoshop are not necessarily kosher either. So all in all, I'm just nervous. Especially because this free space is disappearing quicker than I imagined!

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a heavily-used computer with a 5-year-old drive. I would be more surprised if it didn't have issues.

Two things you can try:

Step 1. Clone your drive to an external drive using something like Carbon Copy Cloner. Do NOT use block copy mode or Disk Utility, that copies the problems as well.

Step 2. Boot from something else, like the clone, reformat your internal drive and clone back (you can use block copy this time).

If that doesn't solve the issues, your drive has hardware problems. Replace it with an SSD and your issues will go away, plus you will get a huge speed increase.

Comment: Too many words dude, gotta explain it to me a little more in detail